# Уточнение ли это?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли здесь запятая, если учитывать, что в предложении говорится о двух людях - муже и жене?

Все расчеты на прочность делали сами вместе с женой.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь слово "сами" трудно отнести к определённому количеству людей: это может быть группа единомышленников, работавшая вместе с женой говорящего. Нужно как-то изменить.

```
Все расчёты на прочность мы делали сами - я вместе с женой.
```

(здесь уточняется, кто это "мы")

```
Все расчёты на прочность мы с женой делали сами.
```

(если жена - такой же работник и от неё можно было этого ожидать)

Comment: Спасибо, но там это из текста явствует, поэтому нужно оставить, как есть...

Answer (score 0):

Это пояснение, а не уточнение (объем понятия не сужается, одно и то же называется другими словами: сами = я и жена). Но, поскольку речь идет о двух людях, смысл передан некорректно. "Сами вместе с женой" - это мы и чья-то жена. "Сами, вместе с женой" - это многозначно: то ли мы и чья-то жена, то ли я и жена. Следует написать "сами, я и жена" или "сами, я вместе с женой". А лучше "Все расчеты я делал сам вместе с женой" или "Все расчеты мы с женой делали сами".